# Yii "framework" sub-folder not visible from apache? [error 403]

Tags: php, windows, apache, permissions, yii

I'm having quite a weird problem here.

I have just pasted the **Yii** folder into my htdocs folders and, for some reason, apache can't see one specific folder within the Yii folder, which is called "framework". I.e., when I type http://localhost/yii , apache correctly lists all sub-folder within the Yii folder **except** for the "framework" folder!

When I try to call this folder directly from the browser (i.e. writing http://localhost/yii/framework) I get a **403 Access forbidden** error.

I'm at a loss here, why isn't apache listing one single folder? The folder which it cannot see is no different from the ones it *can* see.. I've even removed the read-only attribute from all folders within htdocs but to no avail.

P.S.: my OS is windows Vista sp2

Comment: If I remember correctly,  you will find an .htaccess file that define 403 error code. Did you check it?

Comment: I'm not using any .htaccess files. I've just downloaded xampp and am using the defaultest possible version of apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are even trying to view the framework folder directly. It *does* have an .htaccess file in it which says "deny from all". Just make sure you have the correct path for the "yii.php" file inside the framework folder set in the index.php file in your web root.

PHP can include files that are inside "deny from all" folders but you can't browse them directly via a web browser.

Try working through one of tutorials from the start:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app
- http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/

Comment: Oh.... You're right about the .htaccess file inside that folder. So that is what's stopping apache from listing it? That makes total sense. But if the whole folder is forbidden, wouldn't requests to any file (like the yii.php file) therein also be unreachable?

Comment: Yes, all files within the folder will be unreachable to web requests, but since PHP includes are done at the filesystem level, it doesn't use Apache permissions -- only file permissions will determine if those files can be accessed by PHP.